# Why do Google Trends for search terms show strong weekly fluctuations for terms like selenium?

Tags: google-trends

Why does Google Trends for search terms show strong weekly fluctuations.

Here is link to the google trends report for selenium in the US during last 90 days: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%203-m&geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0c828v

There is a significant fluctuation that looks weekly.  I am wondering if there is a flaw in google's data or reporting. Or does the search for "selenium" and other similar technical terms happen 50% less around the weekends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because people do not work at the weekend :)